# How do I scale a texture within the inside of a PolygonRegion?

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a Box2D body which plays the role of the ground, and PolygonRegion, to give the body a texture. I want to texture repeat inside the PolygonRegion, to fill the whole body with a small image. However, there is a problem: the texture which I use stretches up, inside the PolygonRegion. Maybe it happens because the texture greater than the body.

How do I scale a texture within the inside of a PolygonRegion?